# Nautilus: is there a way to change a symlink using Nautilus?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nautilus

Is there a way to change a symlink using Nautilus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Unix symbolic links cannot be edited; they can only be deleted and re-created with a new target. Nautilus follows this model.

Comment: can a symlink be created using Nautilus?

Comment: Create a link by right-clicking on the desired target and choose "Make Link". You can then take the created "Link to X", rename it, and move it wherever you want.

Comment: You can do this more quickly using drag-and-drop, but with the middle or right mouse button (can't remember which).

Comment: @Lee B.  Drag witht he middle mouse button, whne you let go, you get a context menu, one of the options is "Make Link"

Answer (score 0):

The symlink can be recreated thru a nautilus script.

There is these ones:
[sec.Symlink.Edit.NautilusScript.sh](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/sec.Symlink.Edit.NautilusScript.sh), this one  use zenity graphical ui to help on it.
[sec.Symlink.MakeRelative.NautilusScript.sh](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/sec.Symlink.MakeRelative.NautilusScript.sh)

They are present and depend on [ScriptEchoColor packages](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scriptechocolor/files/Ubuntu%20.deb%20packages/).

And must be symlinked to `$HOME/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/`